# Page becomes blank when adding a ui-view with name

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I'm using Angular `UI-Router` in my application. I got confused how to use multiple views in a single state may be. I don't understand what wrong I'm doing also.

Here is my Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/dJNnNNuJ5NvnauTwKrih?p=preview

My routing confguration

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
          url: "/home",
          templateUrl: "home.html",
          controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        })
        .state('dashboard', {
          url: "/dashboard",
          templateUrl: "dashboard.html",
          controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
        })
        .state('report', {
          url: "/report",
          templateUrl: "report.html",
          controller: 'ReportCtrl',
          views: {
            "sidebar": {
                templateUrl: "sidebar.html",
                controller: 'SideBarCtrl',
              }
          }
        })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
});
```

In reports page, I have a **ui-view with name** I'm planing to have multiple views in same page. Also I have some other HTML there.

My `report.html`

```
<div>
   <div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-headingr">
            Panel Title
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            This page is temporarily disabled by the site administrator for
            some reason.<br> <a href="">Click here</a> to enable the page.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In `sidebar.html`, I have some text content. In index I have link to all pages. Dashboard and home link are working, but reports page becomes blank.
Why is that?

**I'm using latest versions of all scripts.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [updated and working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MH4nsz4WrzxGaLYGJL3i?p=preview)

We have to use views object for both:

```
  .state('report', {
      url: "/report",
      views: {
      "": {
         templateUrl: "report.html",
         controller: 'ReportCtrl',
        },
       "sidebar@report": {
            templateUrl: "sidebar.html",
            controller: 'SideBarCtrl',
       }
     }
  })
```

also, because the first view **`"report.html"`** contains the target for the second... we have to use absolute naming

```
// instead of this
"sidebar": {
// we need this
"sidebar@report": {
```

Because that will instruct UI-Router to search for a sidebar inside of the "report" state views...

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MH4nsz4WrzxGaLYGJL3i?p=preview)

Comment: Great to see that, sir! Enjoy awesome UI-Router ;)